# How to use gsutil in startup-script on container-os image in GCP?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm creating my GCE instance with `gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container` and the following startup-script:

```
#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp gs://artifacts.<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com/some-file .
docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
docker pull gcr.io/<PROJECT-ID>/image:tag
docker run --name compose --rm -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/compose:1.26.0 up -d --force-recreate
```

but I am ending with the following:

```
Jun 23 15:22:08 app startup-script[389]: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
Jun 23 15:22:08 app startup-script[389]: INFO startup-script: /var/lib/google/startup-DqGmUt/tmpPyYsVd: line 2: gsutil: command not found
Jun 23 15:22:09 app startup-script[389]: INFO startup-script: ERROR: Unable to save docker config: mkdir /root/.docker: read-only file system
```

I tried installing gsutil also in the startup-script but it bails out with the same problem of /root being RO. Is it actually possible to do this on a COS image?

Answer (score 2):

For `gcloud beta compute instances create` with `--create-disk=...image=projects/cos-cloud/global/images/cos-85-13310-1416-9,...`, I used a containerized `gsutil` in the startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -v /tmp:/tmp google/cloud-sdk:slim gsutil cp gs://BUCKET/file /tmp/
cat /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation [1] it seems gsutil tool runs on Linux/Unix, MAC OS and also in windows. So it seems COS image don't support gsutil. Also I hope link [2] and [3] could be helpful.

Please have documentation [4] as there have some limitation for COS image.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#specifications

[2] [`gsutil cp` from Storage to compute instance running container doesn't copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546490/gsutil-cp-from-storage-to-compute-instance-running-container-doesnt-copy-file/49547156#49547156)

[3] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/453

[4] https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#limitations

Comment: Well... containerOS is Linux.

Comment: Container-Optimized OS has limited or no support for some of the common features you may be familiar with on other operating systems [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#limitations

Comment: Yes, I know what ContainerOS is and I know its limitations. The purpose of the question though is to see whether what I tried to do is even possible in terms of using gsutil command. Are you saying it's not?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. as the error message: line 2: gsutil: command not found, could you please try to install gsutil as the documentation [1]? on the other hand, please provide me steps those you are following with related documentation, I will try to reproduce in my project. thanks a lot.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#alt-install

Comment: In the end I decided just to move to a one-node zonal GCP Kubernetes cluster what solves all of those problems above, thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

**There is a way** to use tools like **gsutil and gcloud** in a **Container Optimized OS**. You can access the **toolbox** to use gsutil to access buckets and then copy the downloaded data form the toolbox directory to your actual VM.

As soon as you started the toolbox you can **exchange files between the toolbox and your vm** with either `/var/lib/toolbox/USER-gcr.io_google-containers_toolbox-20200404-00/` to get data from the toolbox while in your vm or `/media/root/` while in the toolbox to get files from the vm.

More information
https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox