# Gsutil multiple commands in a shell script is working on gitbash for windows but won’t run properly in the linux cli

Tags: linux, sh, gsutil

I have thousands of gsutil commands in a shell script with the syntax
“gsutil cp gs://name of bucket/from-path to-path”

When I execute this script in my windows local using a gitbash it works fine. But when I am running this script in a Linux, it shows that the files are getting copied but when I look in the folder it is empty. Please help me.

Files should get saved in the destination.

The actual commands are:
gsutil cp gs://mycompany/archive/data/raw/integration/THY/2022/12/19/TKT_20221217.zip /home/ds102e/workspace/mft/

gsutil cp gs://mycompany/archive/data/raw/integration/SLK/2022/12/19/SQ9V_20221608.zip /home/ds102e/workspace/mft/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're on a Linux environment where `gsutil` is defined as an alias that runs gsutil in an isolated filesystem (e.g. within a docker container)? You can verify this by running `type gsutil` from your linux shell. As an example, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547156/1405556).